# Javascript - converts dash/underscore delimited words into camel casing

Tags: javascript

Here is a code that works for "underscore" perfectly :

```
   function toCamelCase(input){
      return input.toLowerCase().replace(/-(.)/g, function(match,group1)
      {
        return group1.toUpperCase();
      });
    }
```

But when i tried to add for either "underscore" or "hyphen" in regex,the below code is not working telling me that 
" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined "

```
function toCamelCase(input){
  return input.toLowerCase().replace(/-(.)|_(.)/g, function(match,group1)
  {
    return group1.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why it is not working and rectify the code please ?

Comment: Please tell the input and expected output

Comment: toCamelCase("The_Stealth_Warrior") // returns "TheStealthWarrior".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternate to what @bambam posted is using split and join

```js
function toCamelCase(input) {
  return input.split(/[-_]/).map(e => e[0].toUpperCase() + e.substr(1,).toLowerCase()).join('');
}

const s = 'foo-bar_baz';
console.log(toCamelCase(s));
```

Or using a simple for loop.

```js
function toCamelCase(input) {
  let result = ''
  input = input.toLowerCase()
  for(let i=0; i< input.length; i++){
    if(input[i] === '_' || input[i] === '-'){
      i++;
      result += input[i].toUpperCase()
    } else {
      result+= input[i]
    }
  }
  return result
}

const s = 'foo-bar_baz';
console.log(toCamelCase(s));
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your regex to `/[-_](.)/g`

```js
function toCamelCase(input) {
  return input.toLowerCase().replace(/[-_](.)/g, function(match, group1) {
    return group1.toUpperCase();
  });
}

const s = 'foo-bar_baz';
console.log(toCamelCase(s));
```

Comment: You are the best.Thanks a ton @bambam .